# Защита от частой перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, cookie

```
$time = time();
setCookie('time', $time, time() + 3600);
```

Как дальше прописать условие, если, например, в 3 секунды страница обновляется 2 раза, то выбивало "Слишком быстро?"

Comment: при  каждом обращении к скриптам - пишем значение в сессии, а-ля `lastAction`, если `currentTime - lastAction <= minTime`, тогда - слишком часто.

PS: 3 секунды это очень много

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо строить приложения так, что бы не боятся частых перезагрузок. Почитайте про кеширование. Единственное что вас должно беспокоить это перезагрузка страницы с отправленной формой.

Comment: @ksladkov, не помогло..

Answer (score 1):

Вот что приходит в голову сразу.

При каждом новом обновлении страницы инкрементировать некую переменную сессии, и, соответственно, писать в массив, заведенный в сессии время, когда был произведен первый инкремент и последний. Когда переменная сессии = 3, то смотрим время, когда был произведен первый инкремент, т.е переменная-счетчик обновлений страницы стала равна единице. Вычитаем из текущего времени то, что получили. Если результат более 2 секунд, делаем сообщение...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_COOKIE['time'] <= time()+3){
    echo "Слишком быстро!";
}
```

Учтите, что одна страница может грузиться 3 секунды. Оповестите, пожалуйста, о результате.

Comment: `$time = time();
setCookie('time', $time, time() + 3600);`

`if($_COOKIE['time'] <= time() + 3){
 echo "Слишком быстро!";
}`

Всегда выводит "Слишком быстро!". +3 изменял на +10 и всё равно...

Comment: а если time() + 3 в скобки заключить?

Comment: @atnartur, прежде чем давать советы, вы бы сначала сам php выучили бы, ладно?

Comment: @atnartur, не помогло :(

Comment: @johniek_comp, а в чём ошибка то?

Comment: во всем, будет нотис это раз и ф-я time возвращает время в unix формате, надо курить mktime или что-то типа такого что бы время добавить, но я не буду отвечать, это все есть в учебниках, как время добавлять, как с куками работать...

Comment: @johniek_comp, кроме Вас никто не поможет. А сам я пруф в этих mktime, time и т.д..

Comment: Поменяйте местами проверку условия и setCookie, и все будет хорошо. А то пишете текущее время в куку и тут же его проверяете.
if($_COOKIE['time'] <= time() + 3){
    echo "Слишком быстро!";
}
$time = time();
setCookie('time', $time, time() + 3600);